# Len Function in python. Declared but require assistance on the -1

Tags: python

I just needed some clarification on the code line below:

```
len=number_of_elements-1
```

I understand len function giving me the number of items in the list. However, what does the -1 mean?

Comment: This code will re-assign the name `len`, and the function `len` with the same name will thus not be (easily) available anymore.

Comment: The code as shown would not call the ``len`` function. It reassigns the name ``len`` to some integer value, hiding the ``len`` function. That's usually not a sensible thing to do.

Comment: It depends so much on context you use it with. Could you tell a little bit more about your problem?

Answer (score 2):

It means *minus one*. Subtract 1 from `number_of_elements` and assign the result to a variable named `len`.

[Good Python style](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) would have spaces in between the operators and operands. It's also a bad idea to name a variable `len` since there's a built-in function `len()`.

```
length = number_of_elements - 1
```